# Chrome Extension: accessing DOM of tab that is not currently highlighted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access the DOM of another tab that is not currently selected? I know that you have to access the DOM in the content script, but for example,

```
document.title
```

would select the title of the current tab. Would it be possible to select the title of a tab that is not selected and change it?

I am able to get the title of a different tab and change it but I don't know how to actually apply the change to the page.

Comment: **Each tab** has its own separate instance of your content script.

Comment: Oh so I would have to use chrome.tabs.sendmessage for that specific tab id to send it to the content script to access that tab's content script